# How to authenticate nginx with ldap?

Tags: nginx, ldap

I follow this reference https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap/blob/master/README.md and try to integrate nginx and LDAP.

my nginx.conf setting:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
        ldap_server ldap_local {
        url "ldap://localhost/cn=Manager,dc=xinhua?uid?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)";
        binddn "cn=Manager,dc=xinhua,dc=org";
        binddn_passwd "xxxxxx";
        require group "cn=config,ou=People,dc=xinhua,dc=org";
        group_attribute "memberUid";
        group_attribute_is_dn off;
        require valid_user;
        satisfy all;
}
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    auth_ldap "Forbidden";
    auth_ldap_servers ldap_local;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

My question is how to authenticate the username and password which are in LDAP.
[image]

[image]

This is my first time to use LDAP.

Now, I don't know what is the username and password.

When I try the username and password in `.htpasswd`. It doesn't work.

Comment: .htpasswd doesn't work with nginx, use like this
`location / {
auth_basic "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file auth/htpasswd;
proxy_pass ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Why not via https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth ? It's daemon, use something like

```
     location = /auth-proxy {
        internal;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-URL "ldap://127.0.0.1:389";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(uid=%(username)s)";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BaseDN "dc=example,dc=com";
    }
    location /private-storage {
        auth_request /auth-proxy;
        proxy_pass http://application-backend;
    }
```

Comment: Is there anywhere that compares the two approaches to nginx ldap auth? ( https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth and https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap )? It would be good to know the trade-offs between one and the other.